# Group by id and get order by total count in mongoose express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a collection like that:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f54b3333367b91bd09f4485"
},
"products": [
    {
        "_id": 20,
        "name": "Türk Kahvesi",
        "price": 8,
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": 22,
        "name": "Dibek",
        "price": 10,
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": 21,
        "name": "Damla Sakızlı T.K.",
        "price": 10,
        "count": 1
    }
],
"deskId": "5f53473611f7490d3c860ccd",
"waiterId": "1",
"deskName": "Ü2",
 },


{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f54af663367b91bd09f4483"
},
"products": [
    {
        "_id": 20,
        "name": "Türk Kahvesi",
        "price": 8,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": 21,
        "name": "Damla Sakızlı T.K.",
        "price": 10,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": 22,
        "name": "Dibek",
        "price": 10,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": 23,
        "name": "Menengiç",
        "price": 10,
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": 25,
        "name": "Double Espresso",
        "price": 15,
        "count": 6
    }
],
"deskId": "5f53473611f7490d3c860ccd",
"waiterId": "1",
"deskName": "Ü2",
 }
```

And my goal is, getting all data order and group by product._id and show totalPrice(price*count),products.name, _id and totalCount. This is actually to show us a report product by product. If you need any more information, Just ask.  Sample result:

```
{
{
    "_id": 20,
    "name": "Türk Kahvesi",
    "totalCount": 3,
    "totalPrice": 24
},
{
    "_id": 22,
    "name": "Dibek",
    "totalCount": 3,
    "totalPrice": 30
},
{
    "_id": 21,
    "name": "Damla Sakızlı T.K.",
    "totalCount": 2,
    "totalPrice": 20
},
{
    "_id": 23,
    "name": "Menengiç",
    "totalCount": 1,
    "totalPrice": 10
},
{
    "_id": 25,
    "name": "Double Espresso",
    "totalCount": 6,
    "totalPrice": 90
}
}
```

We can use aggregate on something. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still new to MongoDB, but I think this aggregate pipeline is what you're looking for. That said this is the kind of thing you should research yourself using the documentation, but as long as you understand the thought process you'll learn something so it's all good!

```
[

        {
          $unwind: {
            path: '$products',
            // Here we are seperating each item in the products array of
            // the user(I presumed your objects were users, or carts maybe)
            // It will now be available to the next stage of the pipeline as
            // a singular object for each item in the array,
            // see the picture below for how this works practically.
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            // Now we're going to restructure the object to
            // center around the id field of the products, and
            // at the same time we can add up the total price
            // and count of each item.
            _id: '$products.id', // This is the selector for the grouping process (in our case it's the id)
            item: { $first: '$$ROOT.products' }, // this is me thinking you'll want access to the item in question for each total.
            totalCount: { $sum: "$products.count" }, // adds to totalCount EACH $products.count that we have
            totalPrice: { $sum: { $multiply: ["$products.price", '$products.count'] } }, // self explanatory
          }
        }
]
```

this is what unwind does to your array and object
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
[image: Foor fighters]

**NB** I modified/removed some variable names(_id, oid) for practical reasons, you'll have to parse through which ones and this code will most likely not work right away if copy-pasted.

Comment: woww.. It's perfect code. Thank you very much for your wonderful answer.. :))

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project!
Also, my favorite way to learn things with MongoDB is to play around with the aggregation pipeline editor in MongoDB Compass !

Comment: Yess absolutely, I use use MongoDB Compass for aggregation, too. However, I am new in this platform. So, there are to much time for learn aggregation completely :)

Comment: @Guillame Richard can I ask a last question. If I want to filter by createdAt, how can I do?. I think I should use match but I didn't do this.

Comment: By the way createdAts was in the first Json objects, I deleted these createdAts , when I wrote the question.

Comment: Filter how? You mean to sort it? You can just apply a $sort on the field. I'm not at my home computer so I can't really delve into it today, but you should be ok.

Comment: Actually I did it with "match". { $match : { createdAt: {gte:"",lt:""}}} like that. Thank you very much :))

Comment: No problem, nice job on the filtering!